# Dapper Execute function that can call PostgreSQL function and return rows affected from update or insert

Tags: c#, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, dapper

I am trying to create a postgresql function that does an update. I want to get the rows affected. I know this can be done by using `GET DIAGNOSTICS rows_affected = ROW_COUNT`. But I am trying to use the Dapper `Execute` function which can return rows affected on its own. As far as I've been able to determine, that only works if you've got a hardcoded query you're calling, e.g. in C#

```
IDbConnection dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnection)
string command = "UPDATE myschema.mytable SET email = '' WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@%';"
int rowsAffected = dbConnection.Execute(command);
```

I would like to create a function that does the same thing, and have Dapper call it with `Execute` as opposed to `Query`. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Xtream"."fnUpdateUserID" () RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE myschema.mytable
SET email = ''
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@%';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

So my question is, is there a way to get the rows affected without adding something like an int return to that function? In other words, get access to this information: "Query returned successfully: 2 rows affected, 11 msec execution time." that returns when calling `UPDATE myschema.mytable SET email = '' WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@%'` directly in a postgresql query window. I know `RETURNS VOID` doesn't work for what I'm trying.

To phrase this in another way, is there any way at all to use Dapper `Execute` on a PostgreSQL insert or update function?

Answer (score 1):

Since I have been unable to find a way to do what I wanted, I went ahead and used the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` solution I mentioned above. I am posting it as an answer for posterity. I still welcome other solutions if they exist.

Change the function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Xtream"."fnUpdateUserID" () RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE rows_affected integer;
BEGIN
    UPDATE myschema.mytable
    SET email = ''
    WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@%';
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rows_affected = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN rows_affected;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Then change the Dapper call like so:

```
IDbConnection dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(strConnection)
string command = "UPDATE myschema.mytable SET email = '' WHERE email NOT LIKE '%@%';"
int rowsAffected = dbConnection.Query<int>(command).FirstOrDefault;
```

Comment: With this method there's no way to use Execute instead of Query in dapper, is there? Btw thank you for the answer it seems this is still valid.

Comment: @LordDraagon It's been a while since I did this, but I do know I never found another solution, unfortunately.